# Multiple Request Parallel and Observable collection

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, observablecollection

how do i add this task to observableCollection? anytime it loops it replaces the items that are in the collection. I want it to loop and store 4 items i.e. 8 items in total. then loop again and add another 4 items instead of replacing the first for items. I an supposed to return photos but if i do i get effort because of implicit conversion conflict between int and Observable collection. 
PS. I still like to maintain the multiple request in parallel

```
private async Task<int> ProcessURL(string url, HttpClient client)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(responseContent);
        ObservableCollection<Photo> photo = new ObservableCollection<Movie>();
        foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(i => i.Name == "div" && i.GetAttributeValue("class", "").StartsWith("ml-item")))
        {

            String image = div.Descendants().Where(i => i.Name == "img").FirstOrDefault().GetAttributeValue("data-original", "");

            photo.Add(new Photo() { Image = image });   
        }
        return something;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question your problem(assumed from the example) is that ObesrvableCollection is created each time you call Process URL. So to  be able to store all the photos from parallel requests you need to  move this ObesrvableCollection out of your method and make it as a private field or property. But to avoid sync issues with accessing the collection from  parallel requests you need to use Concurrent ObservableCollection - an example of this you can find at the following topic: [Concurrent Observable Collection, Dictionary, and Sorted Dictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208361/Concurrent-Observable-Collection-Dictionary-and-So)

Just remove `ObservableCollection<Photo> photo = new ObservableCollection<Movie>();` from the method and add your parsed photos to class-scope property or field with ConcurrentObservableCollection  type.

So for first you need to  download sources from article and get ConcurrentObservableCollection class from there and add to your project. Then change the type: ObservableCollection to ConcurrentObservableCollection.  Inside your ProcessURL remove ObservableCollection photo = new ObservableCollection(); and in the end change photo.Add(new Photo() { Image = image });  to _photo.Add(new Photo() { Image = image });   - so you will be using your property. Do not forget to  clean the collection if you will try to use the collection once more after all your parrallel requests will be finished.

Comment: I have read through the link you provided and i cant seem to wrap my head around it. Could you please show me how you can simplify my code by taking the Observable collection out of the method. I already have a private property like ObsevableCollection<Photo>_photo{get; private set;}